# How to show filenames in csv format

Tags: python

I am fetching file names from my local file directory and there are 411 items there but after printing it shows me file names and I am not able to count them in python and second problem is by saving in CSV format, it doesn't show me all the file names? Where is my mistake?

```
import os

FOLDER_PATH = '/home/bilal/Documents/Books/English/'

def listDir(dir):
    fileNames = os.listdir(dir)
    for fileName in fileNames:
        my_file = open('my_file.csv', 'w')
        my_file.write(fileName)
        # print('File Name: ' + fileName)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    listDir(FOLDER_PATH)
```

Comment: Ok, you have shown your attempt. But here we also need the actual and expected result to be able to help you :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory)

Comment: As an aside, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: I am trying to fetch all the filenames not pathnames.

Comment: It would even be more clear of an example of what you have and what you want... I shall not answer without that. Not that I do not want, but without it I cannot be sure if my answer will address your problem.

Comment: I edited my question. Please read now.

Comment: _I am fetching file names from my local file directory and there are 411 items there but after printing it shows me file names and I am not able to count them_ What do you mean? How are you not able to count them? _by saving in CSV format, it doesn't show me all the file names?_ Nothing to do with csv, you aren't even doing anything csv-specific. The file mode `"w"` deletes the contents of the file before writing.

Answer (score -1):

```
import glob
path = r"/home/bilal/Documents/Books/English/*.csv"
my_file = open('my_file.csv', 'w')
fileList = list(map(os.path.basename, glob.glob(path)))
for filename in fileList:
    print(filename)
    my_file.write(filename)
my_file.close()
```

or

```
import glob
path = r"/home/bilal/Documents/Books/English/*.csv"
with open('my_file.csv', 'w') as my_file:
    fileList = list(map(os.path.basename, glob.glob(path)))
    for filename in fileList:
        print(filename)
        my_file.write(filename)
```

Comment: I am not trying to find the pathnames. I am trying to write the filename. Didn't you read the question?

Comment: @Red Mailers Your question says "How to complete number of file names" for that you can use length of list returned. Your code implies that you are trying to print each file name. Please be more specific  Edited my answer anyway

Comment: Your edition didn't give me answer. I am now specific in my question. I edited it. Please read now. I want it to be written all the filenames in csv format.

Comment: So you want to write all the filenames to a csv file? If you iterating everytime You should open the file as 'a' . If you open the file with an  as 'w' everytime your existing myfile.csv is truncated

Comment: You didn't answer my question. It is not working. Although you understood.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it was flagged for review. Answers with no explanation are often considered low-quality. Please provide some commentary in the answer for why this is the correct answer.

Comment: Updated the answer.